# Sort a value in python list of dict

Tags: python

I am looking to sort a list of dictionary based on a key which is in the format \d+:\d+

The list of dictionary should have the expected key(age)

```
lst = [
[{'id': 'SOMEDATA_31_30', 'age': '31:30', 'values':0, 'hasdata': False, 'name': u'SOMEDATA'}]
[{'id': 'SOMEDATA1_32_29', 'age': '32:29', 'values':1, 'hasdata': False, 'name': u'SOMEDATA1'}]
[{'id': 'SOMEDATA2_22_20', 'age': '22:20', 'values':3, 'hasdata': False, 'name': u'SOMEDATA2'},{'id': 'SOMEDATA2_28_27', 'age': '28:27', 'values':4, 'hasdata': False, 'name': u'SOMEDATA2'}]
]
```

So when I pass the whole(lst) to compare(function?!) then it should give me a list of dict ordered in desc order based on the age.

```
lst = [
    {'id': 'SOMEDATA1_32_29', 'age': '32:29', 'values':1, 'hasdata': False, 'name': u'SOMEDATA1'}
    {'id': 'SOMEDATA_31_30', 'age': '31:30', 'values':0, 'hasdata': False, 'name': u'SOMEDATA'}
    {'id': 'SOMEDATA2_28_27', 'age': '28:27', 'values':4, 'hasdata': False, 'name': u'SOMEDATA2'}
    {'id': 'SOMEDATA2_22_20', 'age': '22:20', 'values':3, 'hasdata': False, 'name': u'SOMEDATA2'}
    ]
```

How should we do this ? Thanks for your time.

Comment: The `age` gives me an `invalid syntax` because of `:`

Comment: Is the `age` value stored as a string? The code you currently have fails with `Invalid syntax` because of the colons.

Comment: Your `age` values are invalid Python values to begin with. If they are strings, you can just use lexicographical ordering.

Comment: Just made them to strings. Sorry my fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted).

```
lst = [
{'id': 'SOMEDATA_31_30', 'age': '31:30', 'values':0, 'hasdata': False, 'name': u'SOMEDATA'},
{'id': 'SOMEDATA1_32_29', 'age': '32:29', 'values':1, 'hasdata': False, 'name': u'SOMEDATA1'},
{'id': 'SOMEDATA2_22_20', 'age': '22:20', 'values':3, 'hasdata': False, 'name': u'SOMEDATA2'},
{'id': 'SOMEDATA2_28_27', 'age': '28:27', 'values':4, 'hasdata': False, 'name': u'SOMEDATA2'},
]

newlist = sorted([x[0] for x in lst], key=lambda k: k['age'], reverse=True)

print(newlist)
```

**Output**

```
[{'age': '32:29', 'hasdata': False, 'id': 'SOMEDATA1_32_29','name': 'SOMEDATA1', 'values': 1},
 {'age': '31:30','hasdata': False, 'id': 'SOMEDATA_31_30','name': 'SOMEDATA', 'values': 0},
 {'age': '28:27', 'hasdata': False, 'id': 'SOMEDATA2_28_27','name':'SOMEDATA2','values': 4},
 {'age': '22:20', 'hasdata': False, 'id': 'SOMEDATA2_22_20','name': 'SOMEDATA2','values': 3}]
```

Comment: This won't sort properly if the number of characters differ in different ages (consider `8:00` as a possible age value, this script would put it at the start of the reversed array).

Comment: What if it is a list of list with dictionary with in each list? have update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `key` and `reverse` argument of python built-in function `sorted()`:

```
lst = [
{'id': 'SOMEDATA_31_30', 'age': '31:30', 'values':0, 'hasdata': False, 'name': u'SOMEDATA'},
{'id': 'SOMEDATA1_32_29', 'age': '32:29', 'values':1, 'hasdata': False, 'name': u'SOMEDATA1'},
{'id': 'SOMEDATA2_22_20', 'age': '22:20', 'values':3, 'hasdata': False, 'name': u'SOMEDATA2'},
{'id': 'SOMEDATA2_28_27', 'age': '28:27', 'values':4, 'hasdata': False, 'name': u'SOMEDATA2'},
]

import re
from pprint import pprint


pprint( sorted(lst, reverse=True, key=lambda v: [(int(i[0]), int(i[1])) for i in re.findall(r'(\d+):(\d+)', v['age'])]), width=120 )
```

This prints:

```
[{'age': '32:29', 'hasdata': False, 'id': 'SOMEDATA1_32_29', 'name': 'SOMEDATA1', 'values': 1},
 {'age': '31:30', 'hasdata': False, 'id': 'SOMEDATA_31_30', 'name': 'SOMEDATA', 'values': 0},
 {'age': '28:27', 'hasdata': False, 'id': 'SOMEDATA2_28_27', 'name': 'SOMEDATA2', 'values': 4},
 {'age': '22:20', 'hasdata': False, 'id': 'SOMEDATA2_22_20', 'name': 'SOMEDATA2', 'values': 3}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using NumPy you can try this:

```
ages = [i['age'] for i in lst]
print (np.array(lst)[np.argsort(ages)[::-1]])
```

**Output**

```
[ {'id': 'SOMEDATA1_32_29', 'age': '32:29', 'values': 1, 'hasdata': False, 'name': 'SOMEDATA1'}
 {'id': 'SOMEDATA_31_30', 'age': '31:30', 'values': 0, 'hasdata': False, 'name': 'SOMEDATA'}
 {'id': 'SOMEDATA2_28_27', 'age': '28:27', 'values': 4, 'hasdata': False, 'name': 'SOMEDATA2'}
 {'id': 'SOMEDATA2_22_20', 'age': '22:20', 'values': 3, 'hasdata': False, 'name': 'SOMEDATA2'}]
```